# Using DataTables, how to specify an element inside a <td> to be searched

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jquery DataTables, and I have a table with cells, each `<td>` contains a `<span>` and a hidden `<select>`, now all I want is to filter on just the text inside the `<span>` not the whole content of the `<td>` which also contains the hidden `<select>` element.

I'm using basic DataTables configuration:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
} );
```

I've been trying for a couple of days now on this site, Datatables site , googling, but couldn't find an answer, so please help Thanks in advance

The code is generated on server, but the resulting table is something like this:
**Please notice that:** `<select>` element is hidden with css

```
<tr>
     <td>
        <span>Text</span>
        <select>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        ....
        </select>
        </td>
    <td>
        <span>Text</span>
        <select>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        ....
        </select>
        </td>   
        </tr>
        ...
```

Comment: Can we have your code?

Comment: @D4V1D, I edited the original post to include a sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the code below to only search `<span>` inside cells in specific columns. Please note that I've used `"targets": [0, 1]` to target first and second column only based on your HTML code, adjust according to your needs.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [0, 1],
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         if(type === 'filter'){
            return $('#table_id').DataTable().cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$().find('span').text();
         } else {
            return data;
         }
      }
   }]
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `data-search` attribute on `<td>` element to specify value used for filtering, then no additional initialization code is required. See below for an example:

```
<tr>
    <td data-search="Text">
        <span>Text</span>
        <select>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        ....
        </select>
    </td>
    <td data-search="Text">
        <span>Text</span>
        <select>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        ....
        </select>
    </td>   
</tr>
```

See [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data#HTML-5) or [example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) for more information on `data-` attributes.