# Datatable filtering href value - Bypassing anchor filters

Tags: javascript, datatables

One of the columns in my table.datatable is the name of the enterprise that are registered on my db. I wrapped the name of each enterprise with an 'a' tag for a quick option to edit the enterprise profile, but the issue is that the filters are also filtering the url.

Example:
I want to filter for "DPVNice" the client and owner of the system.
But the first enterprise, which is "Advertising", and its url is "http://localhost/dpvnice/admin/empresa/4/editar". I tried changing the name of the folder in localhost and it solves this problem, but i can't change the name on production that has DPVNice on it.

Bottomline, is there a way to bypass filtering anything with the 'a' tag?

Comment: I used a hidden column without the URL and filter on that column to bypass my problem, but this makes the table do render slower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-search` attribute on `<td>` element to specify value used for filtering. Below is an excerpt from the manual:

> DataTables will automatically detect the following attributes on HTML cells:
>
> `data-sort` or `data-order` - for ordering data
>
> `data-filter` or `data-search` - for search data

**Example:**

```
<tr>    
    <td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td>    
    <td>System Architect</td>    
    <td>Edinburgh</td>    
    <td>61</td>    
    <td data-order="1303682400">Mon 25th Apr 11</td>    
    <td data-order="3120">$3,120/m</td>
</tr>
```

See [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data#HTML-5) or [example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) for more information on `data-` attributes.

Alternatively you can use [render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) method, detect filtering event (`type == 'filter'`) and return desired value instead. See [my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29886546/3549014) for an example.